# Ubuntu SSH connection hangs when I run ifconfig with IPv6 enabled

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ipv6, ifconfig

I've been playing around with IPv6 and setup a DigitalOcean droplet. The only difference between now and before is that I told it to setup IPv6. More often than not, when I run `ifconfig` the SSH session hangs, then disconnects due to unresponsiveness. The `ifconfig` command doesn't finish when this happens...it only gets past dumping the IPv6 details.

Any place I can check to debug this? My solution right now is just not to run ifconfig.

After reading the comments again, I realized that there is maybe a misinterpretation occurring. My command was only `ifconfig` to display network details, I'm not configuring anything with it so there are no extra details beyond that.

The tip that `ifconfig` isn't in use anymore is the most helpful thing so far. There is so much legacy crap on the net still, it is easy to pick up something antiquated.

Comment: Well you shouldn't run ifconfig anyway; it's obsolete for ten years and occasionally gives wrong information today. Use the corresponding `ip` commands instead.

Comment: Good tip. I'll look into it

Comment: In any strange situation run the `tcpdump` and write the capture into the file. Please clarify, do you have the local access or you mantain the server remotely? Use the `gnu screen` or the `tmux` if you doesn't have local access to keep user's processes running.

Comment: This is pure remote with DigitalOcean. about 3 seconds after the session notices it is disconnected, it reconnects and I can open a new terminal. Good call on the screen, I'll look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a [**MTU issue**](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html) - perhaps the extra IPv6 addresses in the `ifconfig` output tipped the packet size over the MTU limit and the session hangs.

Does the hangup happen with any other long-listings? Perhaps when running `top`? Or when copying files to/from the host? Check the link, it explains what a MTU problem is and what you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks. `apt-get upgrade` works just fine, and so to other package installs. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @Brian It would be a MTU between the instance and *your laptop*, i.e. anything that outputs data to a terminal. Try `scp` from the server to your laptop (in this direction, not the other way around). The `apt-get upgrade` takes a different path, that's not relevant.

Comment: Why would this be a different behavior? apt-get blasts a ton of stuff out to my terminal, same as what I would think ifconfig is doing. I'll try what you suggested though, though I think things have been pretty good.

Comment: @Brian `apt` output is likely line-buffered and each line goes out in a separate (small) packet. OTOH `ifconfig` is simply buffered to as large blocks as possible and these don't fit in your path MTU. That's the difference. Sure, I can be wrong but unless you verify this theory with `scp` as suggested I can't really help you much more.

Comment: That is a fair assertion and something I can work with. Is scp more "raw" than sftp over that same connection?

Comment: I just realized I didn't mention that it isn't consistent. On my first login, the welcome message paused for about 3-4 seconds part way through the output, but it then continued to the prompt without disconnecting. I also did some SFTP and SCP transfers without issue. If it isn't consistent, does that mean it likely isn't an MTU issue? in the last few days, it seems more likely to happen if I haven't connected over the last few hours.

Comment: Interesting you had a fantastic idea, but you don't have much rep. I was having a problem with TLS key exchanges not working with no explanation for why...then I stumbled across this: https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeRouter/Edgerouter-Lite-weird-SSL-problems-on-LAN-WLAN/m-p/2817607 . I adjusted my mss-clamp6 for my IPv6 connection, and voila, everything is working and resolved including this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly happens in your case, but I'll try to describe steps to troubleshoot this issue.

- Check the logs of the ssh daemon. Increase the level of logging. Maybe it'll help to find the cause.
- Don't use the `ifconfig`. It's deprecated. Otherwise extend the question and provide the complete command, that you run.
- Use the gnu screen or the tmux. It keeps your programs running. Otherwise after disconnection the user session is closed and all programs in this session will be terminated. But they should be run to move forward to the solution.
- In screen session run the `ip monitor` command. It shows most of changes and events  in the network configuration. In the other screen console run your `ifconfig` command. What the `ip monitor` command has shown?
- If the previous step doesn't help, run the `tcpdump` also under the screen. You can write the capture into the file with the `-w` option to open it later in the wireshark. Analyze the traffic capture in the wireshark. It requires some knowledge of the TCP, but it shouldn't be very complicated. Your first task in this step is determine what happens with your SSH connection.

I think the steps above will help you in most cases. Extend the answer and I'll try to help you.